# Gaussian filtering

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I'm reading a paper and don't get how they tackle the drift of a gaussian process. We are in the setting of isonormal Gaussian processes.

Let $Z$ be a Gaussian process with covariance operator $\Gamma_{\tau}$ and drift $v\in H$, and assume that $X$ is Gaussian process with drift $Z$ and quadratic covariance operator $\Gamma$ given $Z$.

Then they claim that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\exp(i X(f))]&= \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\exp(i X(f))|Z]]\\
                        &=\mathbb{E}[\exp(i Z(f)-\frac{1}{2}\langle f,\Gamma f\rangle)]\\
                        &= \exp\left(i V(f)-\frac{1}{2}\langle f,(\Gamma_{\tau}+\Gamma) f\rangle\right),
\end{align}

where $V(f)=\langle f,(\Gamma_{\tau}+\Gamma)^{-1}\Gamma v\rangle$.

I don't see why $V(f)$ looks like it is. The paper does not clearly says how they deal with the drift, thats probably where my confusion comes from.
The paper is Stochastic analysis on Gaussian space applied to drift estimation, by Privault and Reveillac.